In 6502 assembly, can I test a bit in memory without modifying the accumulator?
In 6502 assembly, I need to set the value of the Z flag according to bit 2 of the value at address $8000. But I need to do so without overwriting the value in the A register.
I've come up with this code, which seems to work but also seems inelegant, because of the stack manipulation and the need to test twice (using and then cpx because pla overwrites the Z flag):
pha
lda $8000
and #$04
tax
pla
cpx #$00

Is there a better approach?

There's no simpler approach with those specific details - if it had been bit 6 or 7, you could have used bit, and if the location had been in the zero page (and you're actually using a 65C02), you could have used bbs/bbr.  If you're just going to do a beq/bne based on the resulting Z flag value, you could eliminate the X-related instructions by doing the branch immediately after the and - and putting the pla on both code paths.

As alluded to by @jasonharper, 6502 is so constrained that most "code to do this" questions can only be answered properly in the context of the surrounding code. You wanted to preserve A, but most tasks require A. There are other ways of saving A like STA zp, TAY etc. And the output (the state of bit 2) can also be found and preserved in other ways that might sacrifice some other state like ROR/LSR $8000, PHP etc.

To finish a thought, I mention ROR/LSR etc (including ROL) as in tight code you often find a single bit result put in C since it's changed by fewer ops than N and Z. In your code after AND #$04, CMP #$04 will put the result in C (and Z) and so if you use C you don't have to TAX and CPX #$00, just PLA and then use C. Lots of old sacred code for machines like the Apple II set C and used it many ops later. The Rockwell datasheet was in the manual, and we lived and died by the one page summary on page 10 here: https://datasheets.chipdb.org/Rockwell/6502.pdf

If you are allowed to destroy x as you seem to be able to, you can push the status register instead:
tax         ; preserve A
lda #4      ; mask
bit $8000   ; test the bit
php         ; save the status register
txa         ; restore A
plp         ; restore status

It doesn't save you anything in time though. It's a matter of which you prefer.
Edit
As I say in the comment below, although it is no faster than the code in the question, this saves one byte of opcodes.
Another advantage is that this will work for any test where you need to preserve the flags. The original code only gives you the Z flag.

Thanks! I think this is an improvement over the original code - it only sets Z to the correct value once, and the stack/register manipulation feels cleaner.

@user200783 I have just realised it does save one byte. Excluding the actual test, it takes four bytes instead of five.
